# How can I delete the white space between the first name and the family name in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv, cjk

The following is adjusted from the preamble of the Chinese template available on [ctan](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template-zh.tex)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   
\moderncvstyle{classic}         
\moderncvcolor{blue}                         
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{李}{中秋}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}                    
\maketitle
\section{教育背景}
\clearpage\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

There is a space between the first name and the family name. 
[image]
In my opinion, the space is weird in the Chinese context. How can I delete it? Or add a space between 中 and 秋? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch the command which inserts the name:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{李}{中秋}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\makecvhead{\@firstname\ }{\@firstname}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}
\maketitle
\section{教育背景}
\clearpage\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

[image]